# Cisco SG switch interface statistic length of time

Tags: networking, cisco, switch, statistics

I am trying to determine the length of time the interface statistic screen is recording for the bytes columns on my Cisco Sg300-52 switch. I went to the cisco website for documentation but the page does not specify the length of time for the recorded byte statistics. Is it for the length of time the switch has been on or is there another setting that says it is reset daily, weekly, or monthly?

Cisco document reference page: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/smb/switches/cisco-small-business-200-series-smart-switches/smb4809-manage-interface-statistics-on-a-switch.html

Answer (score 0):

For statistics like bytes sent/received, it's since the last clearing of the counters, or the last reload, whichever is most recent.

Comment: So if the switch reboots it clears the counters? Or is it only from the manual trigger? I don't think I have ever manually reset counters so I don't know what what else would trigger a counter reset.